# Should the :password field on a user be attr_protected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

Authlogic makes me nervous because it enforces that on the user model, `:password` is attr_accessible:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :password, :email
  ...

end
```

The reason I'm uncomfortable with this is that the normal design pattern for a password field in someone's settings is that you need to reconfirm the old password before entering the new one.

This prevents someone from changing someone's password (and pre `csrf_meta_tag` also prevented cross-site forgeries too).

**Switching someone's password without permission**

However with `:password` required to be `attr_accessible`, it's simple for someone to submit any new password and break their buddy's account.

I'd like to default the `:password` field to being `attr_protected` so that although it *can* be updated it's up to me to enable that rather than being up to me to protect it.

**Does this type of protection even matter if you have 'forgotten password'?**

Am I worrying about nothing? I do realise that given that you have a "send a password reset to my email" function it's kind of redundant but it still puts that extra barrier in.

**Edit**

I phrased my initial question in a confusing way. I don't mean that I'm using attr_protected to stop people from logging into each other's accounts, I'm using an entirely normal authentication setup.

What I'm referring to is protecting from the type of attack-from-a-friend where you leave your account open on your machine, someone sits down at it and changes your password. This can be (mostly) protected against by requiring the old password before creating the new one. That is perfectly achievable even with password set to att_accessible but requires you flushing the new one first.

I would feel more comfortable if the old password is required to update it and that is all much cleaner if password is `attr_protected` in the first place.

Comment: But the password isn't used as-is; to update something, its crypted value would need to be compared against the user's crypted value. If it doesn't match, the operation should fail, no?

Comment: Unfortunately not - with authlogic's default setup you simply provide a new password and it updates

Comment: I'm not sure I follow-is there an auto-generated "change password" page? (I've never used it if there is.) If not, this still seems pretty easy to deal with since you can still protect it from mass-assignment and set it manually, and/or still do as I said above, no?

Comment: There's no auto-update page generated but if you execute `user.update_attributes(params[:user])` it will update the password regardless of whether the old one was provided. You can manually protect against it it's just that it doesn't smell quite right

Answer (score 2):

> However with `:password` required to be `attr_accessible`, it's simple for someone to submit any new password and break their buddy's account.

You need to make sure that the user owns the record they're attempting to update, whether it's a post, a comments, or their own user account. `attr_protected` doesn't do this for you and changing it to `attr_accessable` doesn't introduce the problem you think it does. `attr_protected` has *nothing* to do with controlling which users can update which records, it only specifies which fields can be updated via mass-assignment.

If you're relying on `attr_protected` to prevent users from altering records they don't own, your system is horribly broken. The access control methods *do not do this for you*. Every write operation should be checking to make sure the user is authorized to write to that object.

All this said, your `:password` *should* be `attr_accessable`, so that you can mass-assign it along with a `password_confirmation`, together with a `validates_confirmation_of :password`. This is completely typical and introduces no new problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately my original question does not seem to have been all that clear so I've corrected it. I didn't mean using attr_protected as a general security step, simply to help prevent a password being updated without the original being entered first

Answer (score 0):

Well,

1. to update the password, one must be logged in so you can easily discard changes on someone else's profile
2. you can add a password confirmation if you want to (personally, I'd do that)
3. Even if you have some 'forgotten password' feature, you should let users change their password whenever they want to.